# Indefinite article + singluar noun to refer to a group/type of thing in general

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, singular

My understanding is when referring to a type of thing in general we can either use the plural form or a singular with the definite article. For example:

> The tomato is a fruit, not a vegetable.

Or

> Tomatoes are a fruit, not a vegetable.

But can an indefinite article also be used to make a generic reference? I saw this in Google's definition of "scabies":

> A contagious, intensely itchy skin condition caused by a tiny, burrowing mite. Skin condition caused by a burrowing mite.

I found this definition kind of odd, because "mite" as a countable noun means an individual organism that belongs to the mite species. I thought the following would make more sense:

> A contagious, intensely itchy skin condition caused by tiny, burrowing mites.
>
> A contagious, intensely itchy skin condition caused by a kind of tiny, burrowing mite.

I am almost certain this question must have been asked, but I can't find any related questions. What are the applicable grammatical rules here? Also are there other examples?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/147384/71740

Comment: @userr2684291 Hugely helpful!! Thanks! The answer I am seeking seems to be part of that question's premise. I am hoping someone will be more detailed in outlining the rules surrounding singular noun and generic reference.

Comment: My pleasure! For a more detailed explanation, read what the author of the answer [linked](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), which is a summary of [their work](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/dissertation/), which is again linked on that website ("a dissertation"). More specifically, part 4 deals with the relevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest if you just remember this:

Basically, you don't use *a/an* with plural nouns at all.

Why?  Mostly because when you use a plural noun, you either:

- mean it as a type or abstractly (no article)

  > I like socks on my feet (given anything, if that thing is type=sock, I like it on my feet, but I, for example, might not even have seen a sock today, or be near one at the moment)
  >
  > Socks are neat (abstract, I'm talking about attributes of *sock*)
- are talking about a group of X such you do not mean "any X"

  > I like those socks on my feet (I do not mean *any socks*, but specifically *those socks*)

Since the indefinite article has a lot of overlap in meaning with *any*, it doesn't work when you have a group of something you are talking about (because you no longer mean *any X*).

If you really mean "any group of X" you have to actually say that, with *any X* or *set of X*.

> I like a set of socks on my feet.

Answer (score 0):

The grammatical books on the English usage give five models, which can be used for defining a noun as a representative of some class (type) of referents.

One of such models is that: indefinite article + countable noun in the singular:'A dog likes to eat manufactured food.' However, it is forbidden to use such model if we talk about a place (location) of animals, of placing things, or residence of humans of some type.

That is why it's impossible to say, for example, such utterence as: (*)'An Indian tiger lives on the Indian subcontinent.' We must say instead such sentence as: 'Indian tigers live on the Indian subcontinent.'

So, from this point of view the sentence 'A contagious, intensely itchy skin condition caused by a tiny, burrowing mite. Skin condition caused by a burrowing mite.' is valid in the modern English usage.

Although your suggestions are also not prohibited and not without their own semantic advantages.