# Plural or Singular form for fruit names

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I have a question regarding fruit names. When writing about fruit, I'm confused about which form I should use – singular or plural. I'm not even sure if they are actually count nouns or mass nouns or uncountable nouns.

**Examples:**

I heard banana is good for health.

Lychee, mango, and papaya are popular fruits in my country.

He could taste hints of kiwi fruit, orange, and apple in his drink.

Are the sentences above correct? If yes, why? Is it because they underlined words are uncountable nouns? Mass nouns? Material nouns?

I understand the common usage of the singular and plural form of say, the word, 'banana'.

I ate a banana for breakfast. (Banana - singular)

I ate two bananas for breakfast. (Bananas - plural)

I heard banana is good for health. (The "banana" in this sentence... is it a mass noun?)

I'm sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: Related: [My favorite fruit is grape/grapes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161456/my-favorite-fruit-is-grape-grapes).

Comment: Related: [Indefinite article + singluar noun to refer to a group/type of thing in general](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165081/indefinite-article-singluar-noun-to-refer-to-a-group-type-of-thing-in-general).

Comment: There is also [Is using “fruits” as the plural of “fruit” acceptable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25147/is-using-fruits-as-the-plural-of-fruit-acceptable) on the sister site EL&U.